# How to encrypt a file in a CLI and decrypt it with iOS?

Tags: ios, encryption, openssl, aes

I have some problems decrypting a file encrypted with openssl in a bash. Below is what I did step by step. I can't figure out where does it go wrong.

The original file (ended with newline) :

```
123456
abcdef
ghijkl
```

Generate 32 bytes long random password :

```
$ openssl rand -hex 32
fec8950708098e9075e8b4df9a969aa7963c4d820158e965c7848dbfc8ca73ed
```

Encrypt the file :

```
$ openssl aes-128-ecb -in original.txt -out encrypted.txt
```

About the encrypted file :

```
$ file encrypted.txt
encrypted.txt: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CR line terminators, with overstriking
$ cat encrypted.txt
Salted__??\z?F?z????4G}Q? Y?{ӌ???????b*??
```

Code to call the decrypt method :

```
NSData *myDataDec = [self aesDecrypt:@"fec8950708098e9075e8b4df9a969aa7963c4d820158e965c7848dbfc8ca73ed" data:myData];
NSLog(@"decrypted: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myDataDec encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

Method to decrypt :

```
- (NSData *)aesDecrypt:(NSString *)key data:(NSData *)data
{  

    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise  
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)  
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)   // fetch key data  
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
    NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];   
    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or equal to the input size plus the size of one block.  //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, 
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128, 
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, 
                                          kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,             
                                          [data bytes], 
                                          dataLength, /* input */             
                                          buffer, 
                                          bufferSize, /* output */             
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);  
    NSLog(@"cryptStatus: %d", cryptStatus);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) 
    {   
        NSLog(@"aes success");
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation   
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];  
    }   
    NSLog(@"aes error");
    free(buffer); //free the buffer;  
    return nil; 
}
```

Logs :

```
2012-09-01 15:08:51.331 My Project[75582:f803] cryptStatus: -4304
2012-09-01 15:08:51.332 My Project[75582:f803] aes error
2012-09-01 15:08:51.332 My Project[75582:f803] decrypted:
```

kCCDecodeError details :

```
kCCDecodeError - Input data did not decode or decrypt properly.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSL uses a nonstandard format. AESencrypt is very broken (and insecure). Put them together and it's not going to work. See [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor) for an OpenSSL-compatible solution on iOS. OpenSSL has a lot of problems itself, but it's the best commandline option I can recommend right now.

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to be adding padding when encrypting the file.  You appear to be expecting PKCS7 padding when decrypting.  The decryption method will automatically check for the correct padding.  If it finds incorrect padding, then it will throw an error.

Add PKCS7 padding to your encryption method and see what happens.

Also note that ECB is not a secure mode.  Use CBC or CTR modes for preference.  Use GCM mode if you require authentication as well as encryption.

Comment: How to add PKCS7 padding to my encryption ? I tried by replacing kCCOptionPKCS7Padding by kCCOptionECBMode, cryptStatus is now "sucess", but the result returned is not properly decrypted.

Comment: What do you get?  If it is the correct text, with added bytes at the end, then the added bytes are the padding and can safely be removed.

Comment: I get a non-human readable text: ¨øh øR3CBFCJÊVÈx+ô«Ó;ìÛ:å§sðiQ*o[Äü and always the same even if I change the password for anything else, same if I change NSUTF8StringEncoding by NSASCIIStringEncoding.